# Laravel Issue with @extend layouts

Tags: php, laravel, web, frameworks

I am newbie to PHP Laravel Framework. I am facing a issue regarding extending layouts using `@extends`.
Here is the scenario:-

I am having a **default Layout** `(layout->index.blade.php)`, and a view extending that layout **detailjournal.blade.php** `(journal->detailjournal.blade.php)`. Now i want to create **partials** inside **journal folder**. It contains `leftSection.blade.php` and `rightSection.blade.php`. What i need is to yield these two partials into the `detailsjournal.blade.php`.

I have tried using `@include`, but i want to `@yield`.

Is this possible? If yes then
how can i achieve it?

```
here is the folder structure.
|-views
  |-layouts
    |- default.blade.php
  |-journal
    |-partials
      |-leftSection.blade.php
      |-rightSection.blade.php
    |-detailsjournal.blade.php
```

Comment: Watch laracast laravel tutorial it will help you learn a lot

Comment: Laravel has good documentation you can read about layouts in this section https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: more like blade issue than laravel . Blade is not exclusive to laravel

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `@include('journal.leftSection')` and `@include('journal.rightSection')` where you want them included.

Comment: tried this already. My question is can't i yield those partials?

Comment: `@yield` simply defines an area that can be populated with content by templates extending the layout. If you want to show a partial somewhere on your page, then `@include` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

if u want to include just use

```
@include('journal.leftSection')
```

if your files in includes folder then

```
@include('include.journal.leftSection')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
@section('detailsJournal') 
<div class="">
    @include('journal.partials.leftsection')
    @yield('content')
</div>
<div class="">
    @include('journal.partials.rightsection')
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.